# Introduction to Fourier Analysis Question, Chapter 6 exercise 7

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am currently enrolled in a Fourier analysis class and I am having such trouble with this problem
[question description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMgbM.png)

Would anyone be able to help me understand what to do?

Comment: Its recommended to make your question stand-alone versus expecting users to click on links and also to show your efforts.

Comment: Use the Fourier transform on the PDE to turn it into an ODE. Solve the ODE using elementary techniques. Take the inverse Fourier transform to get the solution to the PDE. The other points can be verified directly.